# Mongodb config file empty. How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I am having problem with Mongodb regarding authentication, and was hoping to fix it by editing the config file. The first time I was able to edit it and it contained text. I then uninstalled Mongo and reinstalled it, and it is empty now. The command line I use is:

```
nano /etc/mongo.conf
```

I reinstalled it a couple more times, still can't figure it out. How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you install it ? Please specify are you using it as a service. It means are you using                                                                                       sudo service mongodb start      and                                                              sudo service mongodb stop. if its the case please post the content of                                                    /etc/init/mongodb.conf

Comment: What O/S are you using, how did you install MongoDB, and how are you starting and stopping `mongod`? The configuration file path is either determined by a service definition or must be explicitly provided. Note: `/etc/mongo.conf` is an unlikely choice: normally this would be `mongod.conf`, to match the server binary.

Comment: @rresol Yes,  I found it in /etc/init/ under the name of mongod.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `nano /somepath/somefile` it creates a new file if somefile not exists. Then you should look at `/etc/init/` and not `/etc`it's probably your find the config file inside the first directory!